# Jquery Mobile with checkboxes are slow on mobile devices

Tags: performance, jquery-mobile, checkbox, cordova

I have a mobile app where I use Jquery Mobile v. 1.3.1 and PhoneGap.

On a page there're a bunch of checkboxes. When I run the app the list with checkboxes respond very slow when you check/uncheck a checkbox.

What to do?

Comment: Could be the 300ms delay. Take a look at [FastClick](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick).

Comment: I have tried FastClick without any success.

I have found out that if you tap somewhere on the page and afterwards click the checkboxes - it works.

Is it possible somehow to simulate a physical click on the page?

Comment: You could try to use [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) to simulate a click.

Answer (score 0):

I used this in Cordova/PhoneGap but I wasn't using jQuery Mobile, just jQuery.

```
   $('input[type="checkbox"]').on( 'touchstart', function(){
       $(this).prop("checked", !$(this).prop("checked"));
   });

   $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
       event.stopPropagation();
   });
```

You could technically do it by using trigger() and pass custom data to the click event handler, but I couldn't get the parameters to go through for some reason. The above works tho.